# can't access my dataframe column on Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am learning Spark and would like to know why I can't access my column, this is the command I am running:

```
shakespeareDF.select(explode(split(shakespeareDF.sentence, " ")).alias("word")).filter(shakespeareDF.word != "")
```

or

```
shakespeareDF.select(explode(split(shakespeareDF.sentence, " ")).alias("word")).filter(shakespeareDF["word"] != "")
```

both commands gives me an `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'word'` but I don't know why.

The funny thing is that this works `shakespeareDF.select(explode(split(shakespeareDF.sentence, " ")).alias("word")).filter(col("word") != "")`

So my question is: Why neither `shakespeareDF.word` nor `shakespeareDF["word"]` works and why `col("word")` does?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing funny or weird about both behavior.

Your first DataFrame you perform splitting on creates and alias. This creates a new DataFrame with that column. So when you call the new created column from inside that first DataFrame, it obviously won't be there and that why you are getting your error.

Now, concerning your second try, you are trying to access the column word regardless it's DataFrame which spark will find inside the new created DataFrame's schema.

I hope this answers your confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Using shakespeareDF["word"] means **THE** column in shakespeareDF. Using col("word") just means column word, it **HAS NOT** bind to a DataFrame yet .

Using bind columns means that the method call can not be chained.

```
explosedDF = shakespeareDF.select(explode(split(shakespeareDF.sentence, " ")).alias("word"))
explosedDF.filter(explosedDF["word"] != "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to Rockie Yang's answer, you also need to save the output of the filter function. Might as well also split on multiple spaces as well, rather than only single spaces, as the latter will result in a sequence of N spaces being split into N-1 empty strings. (The empty strings would then be removed by the filter that follows, but better to just not generate them in the first place.)

```
testSentenceDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('Some spaces',), ('are  repeated',), ('rather    unnecessarily.',)], ['sentence'])
testWordsNaiveDF = testSentenceDF.select(explode(split(testSentenceDF.sentence, ' ')).alias('word'))
testWordsNaiveDF.show()

#+--------------+
#|          word|
#+--------------+
#|          Some|
#|        spaces|
#|          here|
#|              |
#|           are|
#|      repeated|
#|              |
#|              |
#|              |
#|unnecessarily.|
#+--------------+

testWordsImprovedDF = testSentenceDF.select(explode(split(testSentenceDF.sentence, '\s+')).alias('word'))
testWordsImprovedDF.show()

#+--------------+
#|          word|
#+--------------+
#|          Some|
#|        spaces|
#|          here|
#|           are|
#|      repeated|
#|unnecessarily.|
#+--------------+

testWordsNaiveFilteredDF = testWordsNaiveDF.filter(testWordsNaiveDF.word != '')
testWordsNaiveFilteredDF.show()

#+--------------+
#|          word|
#+--------------+
#|          Some|
#|        spaces|
#|          here|
#|           are|
#|      repeated|
#|unnecessarily.|
#+--------------+
```

Note that even when splitting on sequences of whitespace, if your input has empty lines, or lines with beginning or trailing whitespace, then your split/explode will still result in empty string entries that will need filtering. It just won't create multiple empty strings where there were consecutive whitespace in the input.